# How to deploy a dbproj in vs2010?

Tags: database, deployment, visual-studio-2010, dbproj

Quick question, I'm new to dbproj, how do you actually deploy it to my sqlserver from vs2010?  I built the dbproj, and it created a bunch of files in sql/debug folder, then what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure the database project property on the `Deploy` tab and set the `Deploy action:` to `Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database` with valid Target Database Settings, the database will be deployed when you use the `Deploy Solution` action under the `Build` menu.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "Deploy" command on the project. More details on configuring it are on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165.aspx

Comment: yes, tried the Deploy command, and it built a bunch of files in the sql/debug folder, what do I do next to populate my db?

Comment: Did you set up the target database on the Deploy page in project properties?